# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two DropDownLists that I am trying to populate/repopulate dynamically.  On page load both DDLs are filled with distinct values from a column each from the same table.  When either of the DLLs have their selected item changed I want the contents of the other DDL to reflect the change (this is to create a form of filtering on a GridView later).

The logic in the code below says basically that when DDLFirstName is changed check if DDLLastName has been changed previously (if it hasn't been changed it should still say "Please Select").  If it hasn't been changed then put a value of "%" into a variable (so it can be used to say ALL in a query string) and then clear the contents of DDLLastName so it can then be repopulated with last names where the first name is the same of that in DDLFirstName selected item.  This needs to be cleared otherwise it just adds the results of the new query string to the end of the list that was generated on page load

I am, however, receiving a lovely error:
*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*
When I change the DDLFirstName while DDLLastName is still on "Please Select".

```
    Public Sub DDLFirstName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DDLFirstName.TextChanged

            Dim FNvar As String
            Dim LNlist As ListItem

            If DDLLastName.SelectedItem.Text = "Please Select" Then
                FNvar = "%"
                DDLLastName.Items.Clear()
            Else
                FNvar = DDLFirstName.SelectedItem.Text
            End If

            Using conn As New SqlConnection()
                conn.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestDBConnectionString").ConnectionString
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [LastName] FROM [Employees] WHERE [FirstName] LIKE '" & FNvar & "'", conn)
                    conn.Open()
                    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        While reader.Read
                            LNlist = New ListItem()
                            LNlist.Value = reader("LastName")
                            LNlist.Text = reader("LastName")
                            DDLLastName.Items.Add(LNlist)
                        End While
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
     End sub
```

The page_load event:

```
        Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try

            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                FillFNDLL()
                FillLNDLL()
            End If

        Catch exc As Exception        'Module failed to load
            ProcessModuleLoadException(Me, exc)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Protected Sub FillFNDLL()

        Dim FNlist As ListItem
        Dim sel As New ListItem
        sel.Text = "Please Select"
        sel.Value = "*"
        DDLFirstName.Items.Add(sel)

        Using conn As New SqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestDBConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [FirstName] FROM [Employees]", conn)
                conn.Open()
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read
                        FNlist = New ListItem()
                        FNlist.Value = reader("FirstName")
                        FNlist.Text = reader("FirstName")
                        DDLFirstName.Items.Add(FNlist)
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

    Protected Sub FillLNDLL()

        Dim LNlist As ListItem
        Dim sel As New ListItem
        sel.Text = "Please Select"
        sel.Value = "*"
        DDLLastName.Items.Add(sel)

        Using conn As New SqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestDBConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [LastName] FROM [Employees]", conn)
                conn.Open()
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read
                        LNlist = New ListItem()
                        LNlist.Value = reader("LastName")
                        LNlist.Text = reader("LastName")
                        DDLLastName.Items.Add(LNlist)
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: have you tested the query in SQL, are you sure that the reader isn't getting NULL value for reader("LastName")? That error normally means you've tried to populate a variable without checking for null, and it has received a null value.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: You'll also want to make sure that you're not doing anything in Page_Load with either of those dropdowns without having a conditional if(!Page.IsPostback){} around it. If you're reloading anything on every page load it can throw things off in your events.

Comment: The error is definietly being caused by the line: DDLLastName.Items.Clear() Taking this out stops the error happening (but then the problem of data being added over and over to the DDL occurs).

Comment: And yes, in the 'on page load' event both of the DDL are getting populate with ALL entries from their respective table column.  The SQL query runs fine when tested without the clearing of the DDL.

Comment: Have you tried moving the items.clear() to directly above your "using" where you're repopulating? Your query's where clause doesn't seem to be looking for anything from the last name ddl. You can consolidate your list item code too as DDLLastName.Items.Add(New ListItem(Text,Value));

Comment: I have tried moving the DDLLastName.Items.Clear() to different areas within the selectindexchanged event but this always generates an error. If I assign it to say, a button on its own, it clears the contents without error (but is of course useless like this). Thanks for the code consolidation I'll try it to see if I can tidy up my code

Comment: Can you post your Page_Load event as well since you said you are doing things with your DDLs in there as well

Comment: I have updated the original post with the page_load event (along with the two sub routines it calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the last line of `FillLNDLL()` `DDLLastName.SelectedIndex = 0`. Otherwise, the "Please select" option, while rendered and displayed, isn't necessarily "selected" so your `DDLLastName.SelectedItem` is `Nothing`.

Alternatively, you can set `Dim FNvar As String = "%"` when you declare it, and then the rest becomes:

```
If DDLLastName.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    If DDLLastName.SelectedItem.Text = "Please Select" Then
        DDLLastName.Items.Clear()
    Else
        FNvar = DDLFirstName.SelectedItem.Text
    End If
Else
    DDLLastName.Items.Clear()
End If
```

which defaults `FNVar` to all possible matches and only narrows it down by `DDLFirstName` if `DDLLastName` actually changed.

Personally, I'd use the first option.

Comment: Well this problem has now been solved.  Pete, you were indeed right, I was being confused as the selected item appearing to be rendered but its selected value was still actually null.  I have chosen your first option in assigning a value to the selectindex and all is now well.

Answer (score 0):

When you come across this error, the quickest thing to do is step through the code line by line and figure out which line is throwing the error.  Then step through it again and pause right when the cursor gets to the line, check all variables used on the line to see which one is "nothing" or "null" by either putting them in the watch or simply mousing over them(which can be tricky with complex data objects like drop down lists).

If you say that taking away the clear line on DDLLastName fixes the error, then I would say that later when you use the DDLLastName (in this function or perhaps another that gets called after this one), you are getting an exception trying to get at the selected row or something which this function clears.

If you want more help, debug the code as mentioned above until you find out which variable is "nothing",  if you still can't figure it out, atleast post the stack trace of the exception so we're sure the error is at least coming from this function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will get on this now and post the results shortly.

Comment: Thanks Jrud, I have used your advice and narrowed down the item that is giving the error.

Comment: Finding the exact object that causes the error should give you a much better understanding of the problem you're facing, and perhaps give you a clue as to how to go about fixing it.